# code to open .docx in iphone webView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I'm new in iPhone, I'm trying to open .docx file in UIwebView, I wrote the following code

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Arabic literature" 
                                                              ofType:@"docx"]; 
NSURL *url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:urlAddress];

//[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
[_webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/vnd.ms-word" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:nil];
```

but it gives me the following exception:

```
DiskImageCache: Could not resolve the absolute path of the old directory.
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

consider that I copied the file "Arabic literature.docx" in Supporting files.
how can I solve this exception??

Comment: Are you getting something in the NSData or your app is crashing even before that? Is your document saved in your app folder or somewhere else?

Comment: yes I see the document in the application folder

Comment: and are you getting any value in NSdata?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'

Comment: Yes this error means that your file doesn't exists in the bundle path.. firstly copy it there and then find this "NSString *urlAddress"

Comment: Now I copied it again to the folder and it now gives me the NSData, but it gives me a blank page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok why don't you use something like this:

```
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

sorry comments were not working,so had to give it as answer.

Comment: yes this work, thanks, but why it shows the document as a one long page not separate the pages as in office word ?

Comment: This depends on the properties of UIWebview. and if this answer worked,please accept it as an answer so that others may also be helped.