# why can't open .docx file in uiwebview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiwebview

I'm new in iphone, I'm trying to open .docx file in UIWebView

I used this code:

```
NSString *urlAddress = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:docName 
                                                       ofType:@"docx"]; 

NSLog(@"the document url address: %@", urlAddress);

NSURL *url  = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

also this code:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:docName];
[_webView loadData:myData MIMEType:@"application/vnd.ms-word"
   textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

and I'm sure that the file in the resource folder, 
but when run it gives me an exception and say in main.m that

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
@autoreleasepool {
    // here it tells me that (Thread 1: signal SIGKILL)
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MFAppDelegate class]));
}
}
```

Any help ??

Comment: Can you give the full exception that you're given?

Comment: Are you sure it reads `.docx`? I don't see it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html), only `.doc`.

Comment: when I do the second code it tells me that.. EXCEPTION SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError: Could not find the end of central directory record

Answer (score 1):

According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749 you simply cannot open .docx files but only .doc files, which is your problem probably

Comment: hmm look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699850/code-to-open-docx-in-iphone-webview)

Comment: but I tried before to open .docx and it opened simply, but now I don't know what's the wrong. it tells me that : EXCEPTION SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError: Could not find the end of central directory record