# iOS Load and view .docx file in UIWebview

Tags: ios

How to load and View the .docx file in UIWebView? WPS can do it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM4lV.jpg)

Comment: Are you using Objective C or you working on cordova. Hope this works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699850/code-to-open-docx-in-iphone-webview

Comment: I using Objective-C

Comment: Any luck with the link i shared above?

Comment: No, It does't work. Thank u

Comment: Ok let me also try, you are fetching the docx file from a URL or you have it in your bundle?

Comment: from URL.[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"xxx/UITableView.docx"]

Comment: @Lidalu Try my code.It works well for me.

Comment: It works, the file data missing some information，thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data.docx" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
[self.webview loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:url];
```

[image]

Comment: NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"V3.4-1.docx" ofType:nil];
  the path is nil ！！！but the file real

Comment: It works, the file data missing some information，thank you.

Comment: @Lidalu I will appreciate you if you accect my answer.